# How can I overcome this TLE?

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to solve this problem:
given an array of integers `numbers`, I'm requierd to write a function `closetNumbers(numbers)` that finds the minimum absolute difference between any two integers in the array, and print the pair of integers that share the minimum absolute difference. When printing the `pairs[i,j]`, they should be ordered ascending first by `i`, and then by `j`.
The code I wrote passed some tests but I got a TLE on the majority of the tests (hidden tests). I'm not sure why (maybe the nested loop is the problem?), but either way, I can't think of an idea how to **not** use nested loops.
Any suggestions or ideas how to better the code (or why the TLE message) would be greatly appreciated.

Attached the description of the question, list of the case tests, and also my code.

Code:

```
def closestNumbers(numbers):
    numbers.sort()
    d=abs(numbers[0]-numbers[1])
    ans=[]

    for j in range(len(numbers)):
        for i in range(j+1, len(numbers)):
            res_1=abs(numbers[j]-numbers[i])
            if (res_1 == d):
                ans.append(numbers[j])
                ans.append(numbers[i])    
            elif (res_1<d):
                d=res_1
                ans=[numbers[j],numbers[i]]
            
    
    for k in range (0, len(ans), 2):
        print (ans[k], ans[k+1])
        
    return 0
```

[Quetion description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixiyo.png)
[Test Case result list+TLE message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0U5M.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and explain *what the code needs to do* - in your own words, in the question itself, [not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) as an image.

Comment: len(arr) has complexity of O(N), and you are doing it N times, so overall complexity is N^2, perhaps this complexity does not meet the required one.

Comment: your function is empty. put some code inside it or `pass` if you want to leave it empty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import math
from itertools import combinations
numbers = [2, 4, 6, 10]

def closestNumbers(numbers):
    distance = math.pow(10, 6)
    selected_pairs = []
    for i in numbers:
        if not (math.pow(-10, 9) <= i <= math.pow(10, 9)):
            return
    numbers.sort()
    pairs = list(combinations(numbers, 2))
    for pair in pairs:
        new_distance = pair[1] - pair[0]
        if (2 <= new_distance <= math.pow(10, 5)) and new_distance < distance:
            selected_pairs = [pair]
            distance = new_distance
        elif (2 <= new_distance <= math.pow(10, 5)) and new_distance == distance:
            selected_pairs.append(pair)
            distance = new_distance
    for selected_pair in selected_pairs:
        print(f"{selected_pair[0]} {selected_pair[1]}")

closestNumbers(numbers)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I'm still getting TLE, but otherwise I would actually prefer to try and fix my original code and understand how to reduce the computational time.